# How to reload the bootstrap config.json?

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, github, gist

I created a gist with my config.json generated in the bootstrap. 
So I tried reload in bootstrap customize, but return 404 error.

https://gist.github.com/aymone/dba37043a860d4f0abb1

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/dba37043a860d4f0abb1

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/id=dba37043a860d4f0abb1

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: When a user marks as negative a question, necessarily, should provide the minimum, a comment with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=dba37043a860d4f0abb1

Needs the "?" after `customize/?id=yourgistnumber`.